# Using streams to add up the contents of multiple hashmaps

Tags: java, java-8, bigdecimal, java-stream

I have a matrix of HashMaps and I am trying to add up the contents of those HashMaps based on a given input which will match the "outer" HashMap's keys. Take the SSCCE below (with 1 error that illustrates my progress), there are 4 HashMap rows of HashMaps, and I want to add up the contents of the HashMaps in rows 1 and 3.

I can, of course, do this the old Java 7 way. But I would like to do this with Java 8 streams without having to iterate.

```
public class HashMapCollector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, new LinkedHashMap<>()); // row 1
        map.put(2, new LinkedHashMap<>()); // row 2
        map.put(3, new LinkedHashMap<>()); // row 3
        map.put(4, new LinkedHashMap<>()); // row 4

        // row 1
        map.get(1).merge(1, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(1).merge(2, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(1).merge(3, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(1).merge(4, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);

        // row 2
        map.get(2).merge(1, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(2).merge(2, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(2).merge(3, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(2).merge(4, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);

        // row 3
        map.get(3).merge(1, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(3).merge(2, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(3).merge(3, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(3).merge(4, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);

        // row 4
        map.get(4).merge(1, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(4).merge(2, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(4).merge(3, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);
        map.get(4).merge(4, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal::add);

        // Using a HashSet to contain the keys of the rows I want
        HashSet<Integer> keys_to_add = new HashSet<>();
        keys_to_add.add(1);
        keys_to_add.add(3);

        // Java 7 boring vanilla iteration
        BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for(Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(keys_to_add.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                for(BigDecimal bd : entry.getValue().values()) {
                    total = total.add(bd);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);

        // Java 8ish method -- still some boring iteration
        total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for(Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(keys_to_add.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                total = total.add(entry.getValue().values().stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);


        // Java 8 method -- no iteration
        total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> keys_to_add.contains(e.getKey())).map(Map.Entry::getValue). // This is as far as I got

        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to start with `keys_to_add` rather than going over all the entries and checking to see if the key is in `keys_to_add`.

```
BigDecimal total = keys_to_add.stream()
        .filter(map::containsKey)
        .map(map::get)
        .map(Map::values)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
        .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Or, if you prefer to conserve vertical space,

```
BigDecimal total = keys_to_add.stream()
        .filter(map::containsKey)
        .flatMap(k -> map.get(k).values().stream())
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you think is the performance difference between the two options? And between using streams vs iteration?

Comment: Performance should be close enough that you shouldn't have to worry about it.  One advantage of streams over iterative solution is that if performance does become an issue, you can effortlessly convert the computation to run in parallel and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As a continuation on what you had (so you can see the difference), this is how you could complete it:

```
total = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> keys_to_add.contains(e.getKey()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(Map::values)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

I agree with Misha@ though, that it makes more sense to start with `keys_to_add`